# wp-settings.php was deleted from the Azure wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

My **WordPress website hosted on Azure** stopped working which I noticed only yesterday. It might have been down for a while. Looking at the log, I found this error:

> [30-Jun-2015 06:05:17 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\home\site\wwwroot/wp-settings.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-config.php on line 90

Looking at all the files in the server, I see that there is no **wp-settings.php** file. I have no idea who deleted this file except the Azure anytime recently tried to upgrade the site because of the WordPress security vulnerability.

I tried to access the admin page by typing *http://.azurewebsites.net/wp-login.php* which does not work. I can't access any page. I always see the above error.

Should I manually upgrade the site to the latest WordPress version 4.2.2? I have already a custom theme and a lot of data, so little scared to do the upgrade and stop working.

Any advise?

Comment: This question is off topic and is more suited for [wordpress.se]

Comment: Just [download your version again](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) and reupload the files, to recover the missing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure does not have an option of re-install the Wordpress.

I had to do the following:

1. Move the subscription to Standard, open a storage account and backup
   the code as well as the database.
2. Download the latest [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) and unzip in a separate folder locally.
3. Follow the WordPress [instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended) on this page to upgrade to the latest version.
4. Try to login to the admin site. If it is a problem, change the theme
   being used in the table wp-options. Use MySQL Workbench to access
   the database. Upgrade all the plugins and themes.